# I need to access already instantiated object "player" in another class

Tags: java, class, object, instance

I am in the process of learning Java (I am new to programming) and I decided to begin work on a text adventure project. I have a Game class (has the main method), Player class, and an Enemy class. Enemy class has an attack method, while Player class has a takeDamage method. I created a player object in the Game class file inside the main method, and need access to that same instance of Player in the Enemy class in order to manipulate health variable of player, etc.

I tried passing a reference of Game class in the constructor of the enemy class like
`this.game = game` (This was mentioned in another post) but Enemy class still does not recognize the player object. I have other classes but they are irrelevent.

```
public class Game
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declaration of main method

        System.out.print(Art.logo);     //  Prints the logo found in the Art class
        Text.Opener();  //  Calls Opener method from Text class. Displays opening story.
        String playerName = Player.getPlayerName();       //    Calls getPlayerName function from Text class and stores return value in playerName
        String playerGender = Player.getPlayerGender();     //  Calls getPlayerGender method from Player class
        String playerClass = Player.getPlayerClass();       //  Calls getPlayerClass method from Player class

        Player player = new Player(playerName, playerGender, playerClass);      //  Creates a new object instance of Player class,
                                                                                //  named player, using the data retrieved from the
                                                                                //  user using the methods called above
```

```
public class Enemy {

    Game game;

    String name;
    String gender;
    String eClass;

    int health = 100;
    final int maxHealth = 100;

    int strength;
    final int maxStrength = 100;

    Enemy(String name, String gender, String eClass, int strength)
    {
        this.game = game;

        name = this.name;
        gender = this.gender;
        eClass = this.eClass;
        strength = this.strength;

    }

    public void attack(int currentStrength, String weapon)
    {
        System.out.println(this.name + " the " + this.eClass + " hits you with " + weapon);
        game.player.health;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you cant access the player in your enemy class with game.player is because player is only a variable. In order to access it you need to make it a public attribute of Game. Like so:

```
public class Game
{

     public static Player player;

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         //Declaration of main method

         System.out.print(Art.logo);     //  Prints the logo found in the Art class
         Text.Opener();  //  Calls Opener method from Text class. Displays opening story.
         String playerName = Player.getPlayerName();       //    Calls getPlayerName function from Text class and stores return value in playerName
         String playerGender = Player.getPlayerGender();     //  Calls getPlayerGender method from Player class
         String playerClass = Player.getPlayerClass();       //  Calls getPlayerClass method from Player class

         player = new Player(playerName, playerGender, playerClass);      //  Creates a new object instance of Player class,
                                                                            //  named player, using the data retrieved from the
                                                                            //  user using the methods called above
```

now you can access the player from anywhere via

```
Game.player
```

PS. The player was made a static object so you dont need this line anymore (which didn´t do anything btw because no variable named "game" was passed as an argument)

```
this.game = game
```

Edit:

With this line you set your parameter "name" to the value of the attribute "name" (which value is zero because you haven´t initialised it yet). So you override the variable with the passed value from your constructor with null.

```
name = this.name;
```

Instead you need it to be the other way round:

```
this.name = name;
```